# How to remove the left padding of a cell content?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6.1, uitableview

I'm trying for hours to find out why there is this left margin in the custom cell.
The cell only contain an imageView and a label.

```
     |           |
-- imageView - Label --
     |           |
```

I have setup constraints like this to all sides.
I have made the imageView's background red. Hence the red colour indicates the padding is somehow related to the image.  But I can't find anything.

in IB I have set the `Separator Insets` to Custom and set `Left to 0.`

Not sure what else I could do.  Thanks for advice.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried modifying the scaling setting of the image view? Is this with auto layout - is there a fixed width for the image view?

Comment: Indeed with auto layout and a constraint of 110 for image width.  It is set to Scale to fill, but changing that to other modes, makes no difference. Having said that, it seems this solves the problem, but seems rather like a hack than a solution. `self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -17, 0, 0);`

Comment: FWIW, the `Separator Insets` change only affects the line that separates rows, shown in your image as a light line across the red area.

Answer (score 4):

Try the code given below. For Swift 3

```
self.customTableView.separatorInset = .zero
```